# Split list element into lists in python

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list

```
list = ['a:b:c:d', 'e:f:g:h', 'i:j:k:l']
```

What I'm trying to do is make a list of each of it's elements. Something like this:

```
listelement[0] = list[0].split(':')
print(listelement[0][1])

output: b
```

I can't seem to figure out how to create something that works similarly to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try list comprehension to do what you want.

`new_list = [element.split(':') for element in list].`

Also I would advise **against** the use of `list` as a name, since it's a [reserved word](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/list).